# Get Filename from URL and Strip File Extension

Tags: javascript

I need to get just the filename without the extension from a url and can't quite get there.

Here's my url in question:
https://www.mealenders.com/shop/index.php/shop/solo-pack.html

Here's what I've tried:

```
function () {
 var value={{Page Path}}.split("/");
 return value.reverse()[0];
 }
```

That almost gets me there as it returns "solo-pack.html". What else do I need to do to get rid of the ".html" for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following using javascript.   [Pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop?v=control) returns the last element which is a string, and then you can use the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function to get just the filename without .html on the end.

```
function getFilename () {
  return {{ Page Path }}.split('/').pop().replace('.html', '');
}
```

I see that {{ Page Path }} is probably some templating language but you could modify the above script, to get the current URL and then get the filename as so.

```
function getFilename () {
  return window.location.href.split('/').pop().replace('.html', '');
}
```

Furthermore you could make it more dynamic to handle any file extension with the following.  You need to get the index of the period using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and then [sub string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) from the start of the filename up to the position of the period.

```
function getFilename () {
  var filename = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
  return filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.');
}
```

Comment: That second option worked perfectly. Page Path is an existing variable in GTM on the site I'm working on. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @KevinPhillips no problem, you may want to check out the 3rd option if you'll be handling files other than just html.  Also please mark my answer as accepted if you feel like it answers your question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getFileName(url) {
  return url.split("/").pop().split(".")[0];
}
var url = "https://www.mealenders.com/shop/index.php/shop/solo-pack.html";
console.log(getFileName(url));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get rid of **any** extension, you can use `.replace()` with regular expression:

```js
var url = "https://www.mealenders.com/shop/index.php/shop/solo-pack.html";

function getFilename (path) {
  return path.toString().split('/').pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, '');
}

console.log(getFilename(url));
```

This will for example change test/index.html into `index` but `index.php.default` into `index.php` and also `test.name.with.dots.txt` -> `test.name.with.dots`

Answer (score 0):

```
function () {
var value={{Page Path}}.split("/");
var fileName= value.reverse()[0].split('.')[0];
return fileName;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet:

```
"https://url/to/file/solo-pack.html".split(/[\\/]/).pop().replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")
```

Returns:

```
solo-pack
```